# T-SQL XQuery value of attribute "y" where attribute "x" is known

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to query an XML field of untyped XML data to go in a stored procedure.

The field has multiple elements with the same name, and each one has multiple attributes. The query needs to return the value of **c** where the value of **r** (a unique value in the field) is known.
eg. return the value of attribute **c** in the XML field below where the value of attribute **r** "FGH". Each value of r will be unique, so only one line would be returned.

```
<Assets>
    <Cars>
        <Car r="ABC" c="Nissan" t="petrol"/>
        <Car r="FGH" c="VW" t="petrol"/>
        <Car r="XYZ" c="Mini" t="diesel"/>
    </Cars>
</Assets>
```

A redacted version of the query I have tried is:

```
USE MyDB

DECLARE           
@ASSETS XML = null,
@car nvarchar(50)

SELECT @ASSETS = ASSETS FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 26800
SELECT @car = @ASSETS.value('(//*/*/@FGH', 'nvarchar(max)') ;
```

I can see this isn't right, but completely stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the value of the `c` attribute on an element (any name) which has a `r` attribute with value `FGH`. The xpath you want is:

```
//*[@r='FGH']/@c
```

Depending on how you're getting value out, you may need to explicitly get a singleton value. Example:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<Assets>
    <Cars>
        <Car r="ABC" c="Nissan" t="petrol"/>
        <Car r="FGH" c="VW" t="petrol"/>
        <Car r="XYZ" c="Mini" t="diesel"/>
    </Cars>
</Assets>
';

SELECT @xml.value('(//*[@r="FGH"]/@c)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

Result:

```
----------------------
VW

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The `(            )[1]` is to convince SQL Server that you're getting a single value.